# Software Update error message "PPA for Ubuntu Mozilla Security Team"

Tags: update-manager

When checking Software Updater Settings, I get a message about "PPA for Ubuntu Security Team" needs to be changed to "Staging PPA for Ubuntu Security Builds on Mozilla Computers".

However, I see no place to make this change in the "Other Software" panel.

[image]

Comment: Remove the PPA from the sources list. Not sure this even exists. Staging PPA for Ubuntu Security Builds on Mozilla Computers. Mozilla does not make computers.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked and the error message is no more.